# How do you assign values to elements in an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I've tried two-dimensional arrays, varying prototype functions, and I can't seem to implement a score system for this game. Any ideas on what I can do? I want to take the output from this code, which are 6 varying numbers from 1-6, and assign them a value that I can add up to make a score. Ex. If I roll a 1, it would be worth 100 points. What's the quickest and most efficient way to assign a point value to the rolled value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int i, r, diceRoll;
    char player1[20];
    int temp, swapped;
    int roll1[6];

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Enter name for Player 1:\n");
    scanf(" %s", &player1);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
        r = ( rand() % 6 ) + 1;
        diceRoll= r; 
        roll1[i] = diceRoll;
    }

    while(1) {
        swapped = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < 6-1; i++ ) { 

            if( roll1[i] > roll1[i + 1] ) {

                temp = roll1[i];
                roll1[i  ] = roll1[i+1];
                roll1[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }//for

        if( swapped == 0) {
            break; 
        }
    }//while
    printf("\n\n %s's Dice Roll:\n\n", player1); // prints out the dice rolls of player 1
    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Please reword your question and indicate where in the code you're wanting to insert the logic. Please explain what array insertions have to do with dice-rolling.

Comment: I was thinking of making it a function prototype, and calling it later when I want to print out the score. As for the editing, I'm still fairly new here and I'm trying to figure out how to edit my questions better.

Comment: `int xx[] = {0,10,40,90,160,250,360}; int score = 0; for(int i=0; i<6; i++) score += xx[roll1[i]];`

Comment: @chux, it seems to work to an extent. Whenever I do it more than once, the results don't change. Also, could you explain how those numbers work? I have other scores I'd like to implement. Please and thank you.

Comment: I'll leave a detailed answer to others.  `score += xx[roll1[i]]` simple uses `roll1[i]` as an index into array `xx[]`, which in turn is the score to add to `score`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do a straight aggregation of the values mapped to the corresponding point value?  (Unless it is straight 100 * the roll value, in which case it is even easier.)

```
int score = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
{
    switch( roll1[i] )
    {
    case 1: score += 100; break;
    case 2: score += 230; break;
    case 3: score += 540; break;
    case 4: score += 2320; break;
    case 5: score += 13130; break;
    case 6: score += 454260; break;  /* Of course, change to the score you want for each value. */
    }
}
printf("\n\n %s's Dice Roll:%d\n\n", player1, score);
```

"What I originally had in mind was to make the game like Farkle, where 1 is 100pts, 5 is 50pts, and everything else is 0 until you get 3 of a kind ( Three 3s = 300pts, Three 1s is 1000, etc). Any input would be greatly appreciated"  There are many ways.  You can do this easily and use Chux map approach for base and three of a kinds.

```
int score = 0;
int face_score = 0;
int base_points[6] = { 100, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0 };
int three_of_a_kind_points[6] = { 300, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 };
int four_of_a_kind_points[6] = { 
int repeat_counter[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
int kind_mask = 0;
int pair_count = 0;
int three_of_a_kind_count = 0;
int four_of_a_kind_count = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) 
{
    kind_mask |= 1 << ( roll1[i] - 1 );
    switch( ++repeat_counter[roll1[i] - 1] )
    {
    case 1: break;
    case 2: ++pair_count; break;
    case 3: score = three_of_a_kind_points[rolli[i] - 1]; ++three_of_a_kind_count; break;
    case 4: score = 1000; ++four_of_a_kind_count; break;
    case 5: score = 2000; break;
    case 6: score = 3000; break;
    }
}

if( pair_count == 3 ) /* Three pairs */
    score = 1500;
else if( three_of_a_kind_count == 2 ) /* Two three of a kinds */
    score = 2500;
else if( four_of_a_kind && ( pair_count == 2 ) ) /* A four of a kind and one pair (2 because four of a kind counted as a pair in the aggregation phase) */
    score = 1500;
else if( kind_mask = 0x2F ) /* One of each type */
    score = 1500; /* Straight */
else if( !score )  /* score only 1's and 5's */
    score = repeat_counter[0] * 100 + repeat_counter[4] * 50;
printf("\n\n %s's Dice Roll:%d\n\n", player1, score);
```

I have not compiled or run this code, so it may not be 100% correct.

Comment: Stupid question, but is 'case' C, or C++? I've never seen it before, and I'm supposed to be using C.

Comment: What I originally had in mind was to make the game like Farkle, where 1 is 100pts, 5 is 50pts, and everything else is 0 until you get 3 of a kind ( Three 3s = 300pts, Three 1s is 1000, etc). Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I modified the example.  Not sure if the point system is correct or if the code is syntax / semantic error free. But it should help give you an idea.